# Google Apps Script - Classroom - posting announcements with more than 1 URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-classroom

I have the following which I use to post announcements to multiple google classrooms listed in a sheet.
Is there any way to add more than 1 URL to the announcement?
I know I can add URLs in the text body of the announcement, but I want to be able to add multiple URLs as links on the announcement.
I would also like to have the option to post an announcement with NO url, although if that is not possible its not a massive problem.

```
    function sendAnnouncement() {
  var startTime= (new Date()).getTime();
  Logger.log(startTime);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SendAnnouncement");
  var text = ss.getRange(1, 2).getValue();
  var url = ss.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
  Logger.log(text);
  Logger.log(url);
  var data = {
  text: text,
  materials: [
    {
      link: {
        url: url
      }
    }
   ]
  }
 
  var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
  Logger.log(payload)
  var Avals = ss.getRange("A5:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  Logger.log(Alast)
  for (var i = 0; i < Alast; i++) {
    var CourseId = Avals[i][0];
    Logger.log(CourseId);
    var resource = Classroom.Courses.Announcements.create(data, CourseId);
    var logStatus = ss.getRange(i+5, 3).setValue('Announcement created '+new Date());
}
}
```

Thanks
Jon

Comment: Could you share a view  of your sheet to have a better idea how it is structured to replicate this scenario?

Comment: will have to set up a replica sheet, should have time to do that tomorrow. thanks

Comment: No need, forgot to remove this comment after I added my answer.

Answer (score 0):

##### - To add multiple URLs as links on the announcement:

###### Change this:

```
    materials: [
      {
        link: {
          url: url
        }
      }
    ]
```

###### To this:

```
    materials: [
      {
        link: {
          url: "https://www.fiaformulae.com/"
        }
      },
      {
        link: {
          url: "https://www.formula1.com/",
        }
      },
      {
        link: {
          url:"https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.announcements/list"
        }
      }
    ]
```

###### Result:

[image]

##### - To create an announcement with no links:

```
  CourseId = 'XxxxxxxxXXXX';
  var data = {
    text: "This is an announcement with text only ",
  }
  var resource = Classroom.Courses.Announcements.create(data, CourseId);
```

###### Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. With the multiple URLS would it fail if one of the URLs was blank? The URLs would be taken from a cell in the sheet, so they could be empty.

Comment: Yes, specifically you will be getting the error: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' because an empty value is not a valid value in this case. So in your code you will have to evaluate if the sheet has a link value to be added in the announcement, if it does then add the ```materials [Link] ``` snippet to it.

Comment: @Jon you can use [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to go over every cell in the range array and create a new array that filters empty values